# How do I complete the immunologist's request? [spoilers]

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

My gaming group is playing through Pandemic Legacy Season:1.  We've just completed August and located the immunologist.  Now, we have a card full of items to retrieve for the immunologist.  We can't figure out how to get them.

Should we be able to tell how to locate these items? Or will this be revealed in future months?  It feels strange to be given a task that we can't attempt yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a spoiler free answer, I will say that you should expect how to do them to be revealed later if you don't know how to do them now.

Why shouldn't there be objectives that you cannot do. Remember that you only need to complete a specified number of objectives each month NOT all of them.

If that is not satisfying then below is a spoiling hint:

> You get the item for the immunologist by doing the search objectives

Comment: This answer is 100% more legit because of your background in bioinformatics.